# Adding Axis padding/inner margin to Vega-Lite chart

Tags: vega-lite

I have a created a vega-lite scatterplot chart. The data for this chart will always be positive, however it is often zero. In this application, it would be helpful for the user for points who's x or y are zero to not overlap with the lines for the axis

The straightforward solution is to try and manually adjust the domain and range to start before 0 and after the maximum value. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in the configuration instead. I have read through the documentation and, to my knowledge and ability, I have not yet found such a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the lowest point does not overlap the axis, one way to do so is to use the axis `"offset"` property, which allows you to specify the horizontal offset of the y-axis in pixels. For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvAAwA0IAnvAEwC+ph8AjOVXACz2NzWvwDMXEETj8+cAKxCR7cZwC69EAFsIAJwDW8EAAcA9gEsAdlBDkMRgMZ6wxgObxuoAGYGMKMNqLkoFHRm0ARzQIEwMYKANEAKU2FzcPbSofPwC4EGDQyIiogPIIAgMcBBA9Z2csDFMeYlo62iA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 2},
      {"x": 1, "y": 4},
      {"x": 2, "y": 3},
      {"x": 3, "y": 5},
      {"x": 4, "y": 4}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"offset": 20}}
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adjusting the domain and adding an axis offset, you can [use the scale config properties to add padding](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#scale-config) for all scales of a certain type. This will add some whitespace between the axis lines and the location of the closest data points:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "scale": {"continuousPadding": 5}
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 2},
      {"x": 1, "y": 4},
      {"x": 2, "y": 3},
      {"x": 3, "y": 5},
      {"x": 4, "y": 4}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]